# Why Filter::Indent::HereDoc complain when blank line in middle of HereDoc

Tags: perl, heredoc

I am trying [Filter::Indent::HereDoc](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Filter-Indent-HereDoc/HereDoc.pm) which allows one to indent the HereDocument. This is very useful, to be able to have HereDoc that flows with the code logic.

From the above link

> When a 'here document' is used, the document text and the termination
>   string must be flush with the left margin, even if the rest of the
>   code block is indented.
>
> Filter::Indent::HereDoc removes this restriction, and acts in a more
>   DWIM kind of way - that if the terminator string is indented then that
>   level of indent will apply to the whole document.

This module can be installed using `sudo cpanm Filter::Indent::HereDoc`

However, I am finding that if there is blank line inside the HereDoc, then it gives the error

```
  Can't find string terminator "EOT" anywhere before EOF at....
```

Which does not happen when I remove the blank line.  Here is MWE

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Filter::Indent::HereDoc;

my $str = <<'EOT';
    some text
    some text
    EOT

print $str;
```

The above runs with no problem, even though space exists before `EOT` (It would have failed without using `Filter::Indent::HereDoc`)

```
>perl t4.pl 
some text
some text
>
```

Now I simply insert a blank line in between, like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Filter::Indent::HereDoc;

my $str = <<'EOT';
    some text

    some text
    EOT

print $str;
```

and now

```
>perl t4.pl 
Can't find string terminator "EOT" anywhere before EOF at t4.pl line 6.
>
```

If the space before `EOT` is now removed, then it works:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Filter::Indent::HereDoc;

my $str = <<'EOT';
     some text

     some text
EOT

print $str;
```

and now

```
>perl t4.pl 
     some text

     some text
>
```

But the whole idea of using this module is to allow one to indent the HereDoc.

Any idea what is going on?

Information:

```
>perl --version

This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built 
for i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Filter::Indent::HereDoc#DESCRIPTION) says:

> If there is no terminator string (so the here document stops at the
>   first blank line), then enough whitespace will be stripped out so that
>   the leftmost character of the document will be flush with the left
>   margin, e.g.
>
> ```
> print <<;
>      Hello,
>     World!
>
> # This will print:
>  Hello,
> World!
> ```

This is the paragraph directly below the one you quoted in the question. **The fact that it stops at blank lines is a feature**.

Comment: I did read this, but I really did not understand it. And I still do not understand this whole thing. What is the point of using this module then, if one can not have a blank line in here document?? i.e. I am asking, how would one use blank line, and still use the indent feature?  If one can't have blank line, then this whole module makes no sense. Or may be I am still missing something.

Comment: I don't know what the module is for. Convenience, I guess. It's been written in 2003 and the [last release](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Filter-Indent-HereDoc) is 2003 also. To be honest I don't see any use in this. What you could do is monkeypatch it, but there is just one function anyway, so that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: ok, thanks. If this is how it is supposed to work, then it is useless really. Not being able to have blank line in here document makes no sense.